# Sent a POST request with JS, and handling the data with Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm adding a contact me section to a website. I want to be able to send the data from the forms with JS, and then receive and do something with the data with Node. I understand that there are frameworks and libraries that can handle this stuff, but I would like to build it from scratch so that I have a better understanding of what is happening.

I currently have a section of JS (see below) that is taking the form data, and sending it as a POST request to the node script, but I can't seem to wrap my head around what is happening with node, or how to receive the data with the node script. Any help in pointing me in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

```js
const name = $(".name");
const email = $(".email");
const message = $(".message");
const submitButton = $(".submitButton");
const nameRegex = /([a-zA-Z\s-])/g;
const emailRegex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/g;
const messageRegex = /([a-zA-Z\s.,?!$%&])/gm;

const url = "../node/contactMeSubmissionHandler.js"

submitButton.click(function(){
  let nameContents = name.val().match(nameRegex).join("");
  let emailContents = email.val().match(emailRegex).join("");
  let messageContents = message.val().match(messageRegex).join("");
  // if (emailRegex.test(emailContents) == true) {
  //   let emailValid = emailContents;
  // } else {
  //   console.log("Email is invalid");
  // };
  const data = {
    email: emailContents,
    name: nameContents,
    message: messageContents
  }
  $.post(url, data, function(data, status){
    console.log(`${data} and status is ${status}`);
  })
})
```

Comment: " I can't seem to wrap my head around what is happening with node," — Well, nothing at present. You omitted the code you are running with Node.

Comment: It doesn't work like PHP, and node.js code and client-side JS code cannot work together like that. `$.post` sends off a generic HTTP POST request, and you need a running web server to process that request. You could write your own, but you should learn to walk before trying to run. Use express, which means you'd have something like `app.post("/sendmail", (req, res) => { ... });` in your node code. On the client, the `$.post` url will be `http://localhost:3000/sendmail` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to create a server and check the log in console for different request attributes.

```
const http = require('http');

http
  .createServer((request, response) => {
    console.log(request);
    response.end();
  })
  .listen(3000);
```

Make GET and POST request to `http://localhost:3000/` and look for `method`, `headers` etc.

See more [here](https://nodejs.org/api/synopsis.html) and [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html).

Answer (score 0):

I like to write from scratch too. Here is working code which is called from a command line to get a token.

```
//  clientEx.js

var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

const _SERVER = "dcsmail.net";      /* dcsmail.net */

// Callback function is used to deal with response
//
var callback = function (response)
    {
    // update stream with data
    var body = '';
    response.on('data', function(data) {
        body += data;
        });
    response.on ('end', function()
        {
        // Data received completely.
        fs.writeFileSync ("temp.lst", body, 'utf8');
        // console.log ("clientEx.js received: " + body);
        });
    }

if ((process.argv[2] == null) || (process.argv[3] == null) || (process.argv[4] == null) || (process.argv[5] == null))
    {
    console.log ("clientEx.js usage:<user email> <user password> <destination> <GUID>");
    }
else
    {
    var Ef_email = encodeURI (process.argv[2]);
    var Ef_pass = encodeURI (process.argv[3]);
    var Ef_dest = encodeURI (process.argv[4]);
    var Ef_guid = encodeURI (process.argv[5]);
    var post_data = ("f_email=" + Ef_email +
                    "\&" + "f_pass=" + Ef_pass +
                    "\&" + "f_dest=" + Ef_dest +
                    "\&" + "f_guid=" + Ef_guid);
    // Options to be used by request 
    var options = {
        host: _SERVER,
        port: '80',
        path: '/DCSM/tokenP10.php',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength (post_data)
            }
        };
    // console.log ("clientEx.js using " + _SERVER + ":" + options.port + options.path);
    // request the token from the host
    try
        {
        var req = http.request (options, callback);
        req.write (post_data);
        req.end();
        }
    catch (error)
        {
        fs.writeFileSync ("temp.lst", "Host access failed\n", 'utf8');
        }
    }
```

You should be able to adapt that to your needs.